# Quasar Axios request wrong URL (Double URL)

Tags: vue.js, axios, quasar

[The Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLidJ.png)

> when i send request via axios with url axios concatenate url of api
>   with the url of the quasar dev server how can i neglect this
>   concatenation and send the API url only there is any configuration for
>   baseUrl of axios with quasar ?

src/boot
    import axios from 'axios'

```
export default async ({ Vue }) => {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http//:localhost:3000/'
  Vue.prototype.$axios = axios
}
```

the componennt :

```
this.$axios({
        url : 'backend/spots/all',
     }).then(response=>{
        this.allSlots = response.data
     })
```

Answer (score 2):

According Quasar [documentation](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/boot-files#Usage-of-boot-files) you can try it as below:

```
// src/boot/axios.js

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http//:localhost:3000'
})

export default async ({ Vue }) => {
  Vue.prototype.$axios = axiosInstance
  ...
}

export { axiosInstance }
```

to use in some vue | js file:

```
import { axiosInstance } from 'src/boot/axios'

axiosInstance.get('/some-endpoint')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but can you try to change `axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http//:localhost:3000/'` to `axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/'` (change colon place) ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this.
According to quasar [axios boot file documentation](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files#Axios) you can try a more cleaner way...

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

// we add it to Vue prototype
// so we can reference it in Vue files as this.$axios
// without the need to import axios or use vue-axios
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios

// can also create an axios instance specifically for the backend API
const api = axios.create({ baseURL: 'https://api.example.com' })
Vue.prototype.$api = api

export { axios, api }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, in quasar.config.js under build I had

```
  env:  ctx.dev ? { // so on dev we'll have
    API: JSON.stringify('https://my.staging.api/v1/')
  } : { // and on build (production):
    API: JSON.stringify('https://my.api/v1/')
  },
```

removing `JSON.stringify` solved the issue

```
  env:  ctx.dev ? { // so on dev we'll have
    API: 'https://my.staging.api/v1/'
  } : { // and on build (production):
    API: 'https://my.api/v1/'
  },
```