# Axios has wrong URL only with 'heroku local web'

Tags: vue.js, heroku, axios

I've got a problem with axios and heroku. Maybe some short [introduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59919359/quarkus-heroku-and-different-environments) before.

The problem with CORS has been solved and i my apps run on localhost and on herokuapp.com. The only thing which is currently not working is my app running with `heroku local web`.

For the backend call I using axios which is referencing my backend api from an environment file:

```
axios
   .get(process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_API + "/resource")
   .then(response => (this.receipt = response.data));
}
```

`.env.local`:

```
VUE_APP_ROOT_API=http//:0.0.0.0:5002 #5002 is my backend
```

This produces the following wrong axios call:

```
GET http://0.0.0.0:5001/http//:0.0.0.0:5002/resource #5001 is my frontend
```

I cannot explain how this GET is generated. Printing out the request url with

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {
  console.log("Starting Request", request);
  return request;
});
```

is showing the correct URL `http//:0.0.0.0:5002/resource`...

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarassing, I had a type:

http:// instead of http//:

See: [Quasar Axios request wrong URL (Double URL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680554/quasar-axios-request-wrong-url-double-url)